# Switch tab and backtick keys Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, remap

In a very unfortunate chain of events involving my laptop and a set of stairs, I lost my tab key. Not just normal lost, where you can buy another key and slap it back on; advanced lost to where the metal frame that holds the plastic spring assembly has a broken hook.

Anyway, as I'm in terminal a lot, I use my tab key constantly. Is there any way to map my tab key to the backtick (this one ``````````) and the backtick to the tab key? I don't use backticks nearly as often, so I can deal with fumbling with the rubber keyspring for that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run `xev` on a command line and find the keycode for the key (UK its keycode 49) 
then run `xmodmap -e "keycode 49 = Tab`

replacing the keycode from xev when you press that key.

You should now have a remapped key !

to save these you need to run

`xmodmap -pke >~/.Xmodmap`

update you need a modifier too

`xmodmap -e "keycode 49 = Tab asciitilde`

should work

Comment: I've done this, and it almost works; however, I now can't type the squigly (shift backtick)

Comment: edited answer to fix that, i assume the asciitilde is the key your talking about ?

Comment: Yeah. Tilde. Although I still think squigly sounds better :D